# Redefine equation enviroment using nesting

Tags: equations, environments, nesting

Many times I write so long equations that I need to use this sequence:

```
\begin{equation}\begin{gathered}
   ax+by=u\\
   cx+by=v
\end{gathered}\end{equation}
```

I would like to redefine the `equation` environment in order to being able to do something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
   ax+by=u\\
   cx+by=v
\end{equation}
```

I have achieved this by using  `\let` as this way

```
\let\EQUATION\equation
\let\endEQUATION\endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}{\begin{EQUATION}\begin{gathered}}{\end{gathered}\end{EQUATION}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

However, what I would really like to get is this effect without using intermidiate variables. I have tried this

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\equation\expandafter{\equation\gathered}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\endequation\expandafter{\endgathered\endequation}
```

but the only thing that it gives to me is this error

```
Misplaced \crcr. \end{equation}
Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{equation}
```

Could anyone, please, help me to solve this trouble?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not using one of `amsmath`'s environments that already allow several lines, like `gather` or `align`?

Comment: You are missing one more `\expandafter` at the second line. It should be `\expandafter\def\expandafter\endequation\expandafter{\expandafter\endgathered\endequation}`, because you need `\endequation` to be expanded.

Comment: @Vincent. If I use ```gather```, each new line equation will be numbered. If ```align``` is used, all of them will be numbered as one equation, but they will get left-aligned

Comment: @UdiFogiel. Thank you so much!!! This solution is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as egreg, I wouldn't recommend redefining environments in such a way.

You need another `\expandafter` so `\endequation` would be expanded once (and not `\endgather`) before the definition starts, hence the line  `\expandafter\def\expandafter\endequation\expandafter{\endgathered\endequation}` should be `\expandafter\def\expandafter\endequation\expandafter{\expandafter\endgathered\endequation}`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend *not* doing it, because you take bad habits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%% not recommended
\NewCommandCopy{\latexequation}{\equation}
\NewCommandCopy{\latexendequation}{\endequation}
\ExpandArgs{nc}\NewCommandCopy{\latexequationstar}{equation*}
\ExpandArgs{nc}\NewCommandCopy{\latexendequationstar}{endequation*}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{}
 {\latexequation\gathered}
 {\endgathered\latexendequation}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation*}{}
 {\latexequationstar\gathered}
 {\endgathered\latexendequationstar}

\begin{document}

words before the equation words before the equation
words before the equation words before the equation
\begin{equation}
  ax+by=u\\
  cx+by=v
\end{equation}
words after the equation words after the equation
words after the equation words after the equation

words before the equation words before the equation
words before the equation words before the equation
\begin{equation*}
  ax+by=u\\
  cx+by=v
\end{equation*}
words after the equation words after the equation
words after the equation words after the equation

\end{document}
```

[image]

Recommended way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%% recommended

\NewDocumentEnvironment{longequation}{}
 {\equation\gathered}
 {\endgathered\endequation}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{longequation*}{}
 {\csname equation*\endcsname\gathered}
 {\endgathered\csname endequation*\endcsname}

\begin{document}

words before the equation words before the equation
words before the equation words before the equation
\begin{longequation}
  ax+by=u\\
  cx+by=v
\end{longequation}
words after the equation words after the equation
words after the equation words after the equation

words before the equation words before the equation
words before the equation words before the equation
\begin{longequation*}
  ax+by=u\\
  cx+by=v
\end{longequation*}
words after the equation words after the equation
words after the equation words after the equation

\end{document}
```

Just for fun an `\expandafter` orgy for avoiding defining command copies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%% definitely not recommended
\expandafter\def\expandafter\equation\expandafter{\equation\gathered}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\endequation\expandafter{\expandafter\endgathered\endequation}

\expandafter\def\csname equation*\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname equation*\endcsname\gathered}
\expandafter\def\csname endequation*\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgathered\csname endequation*\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

words before the equation words before the equation
words before the equation words before the equation
\begin{equation}
  ax+by=u\\
  cx+by=v
\end{equation}
words after the equation words after the equation
words after the equation words after the equation

words before the equation words before the equation
words before the equation words before the equation
\begin{equation*}
  ax+by=u\\
  cx+by=v
\end{equation*}
words after the equation words after the equation
words after the equation words after the equation

\end{document}
```

The orgy can be a bit tamed

```
%%%% definitely not recommended
\edef\equation{\unexpanded\expandafter{\equation\gathered}}
\edef\endequation{\noexpand\endgathered\unexpanded\expandafter{\endequation}}

\expandafter\edef\csname equation*\endcsname{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname equation*\endcsname\gathered}%
}
\expandafter\edef\csname endequation*\endcsname{%
  \noexpand\endgathered
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname endequation*\endcsname}%
}
```

But this might be better:

```
%%%% definitely not recommended
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npx \equation { \exp_not:o {\equation} \exp_not:N \gathered }
\cs_set:Npx \endequation { \exp_not:N \endgathered \exp_not:o {\endequation} }

\cs_set:cpx {equation*} { \exp_args:Nc \exp_not:o { equation* } \exp_not:N \gathered }
\cs_set:cpx {endequation*} { \exp_not:N \endgathered \exp_args:Nc \exp_not:o {endequation*} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```